# Passing object through WCF so that server receives client changes

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to set up a WCF service so that any changes a client makes to an object I send them are also reflected on the server side. For example, if Assembly A has the following...

```
namespace AssemblyA
{

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServer
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Person GetPerson();
    }

}
```

And Assembly B references Assembly A...

```
using AssemblyA;

namespace AssemblyB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            <snip>
            IServer server = factory.CreateChannel();
            Person person = server.GetPerson();
            person.FirstName = "Kilroy";
            person.LastName = "WuzHere";
        }
    }
}
```

What is the easiest/best way to make it so that the service's copy of the Person object also reflects the changes that the client makes? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method on the server which take a `Person` object as parameter.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServer
{
    [OperationContract]
    Person GetPerson();

    [OperationContract]
    void UpdatePerson( Person person )
}
```

and call that from the client after you have set the FirstName and LastName properties.

```
server.UpdatePerson( person );
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for what I'm trying to do... the example I gave above is very simple, but the objects I actually want to pass through are much more complex - the properties have multiple events and cause UI changes, hardware outputs, etc. I will give it a shot though.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about your scenario? Do you want client events to trigger server actions, or the other way around? Are the server and client on a local network or on internet?

If your Person object has an event you could implement the client code to run the Update method on the server.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond - after doing a little more research I think I was misunderstanding how WCF works and what it would be capable of doing. I have been able to implement something like you suggested that works for what I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are in need for handling events between the client & server, you ought to look for Duplex Contracts with WCF. This is a very good detailed example for you to start with:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF